# Can I obtain a CKEditor instance from the element it transformed?

Tags: ckeditor

I have a situation where I am cloning an element containing a CKEditor instance. After cloning, I change all the ids to make sure I don't have two elements with the same id in the same page. I am having trouble accessing the cloned version of the CKEditor. Indeed, if I access it via the elements id, I get the original (not the clone with the new id). I can access the replaced textarea without problem, but not the CKEditor.editor object that goes along with it. Is it possible to access this object by using the replaced element (and not its id)?

N.B Please tell me what I can add here to make the question clearer...

**Follow up**
I figured out that I was thining about this the wrong way. When I clone the element containing the CKEditor, I have a copy of the element, but the CKEDITOR object doesn't know about it. What I ended up doing is simply removing the html associated to the cloned editor and calling `CKEDITOR.replace` again to replace the cloned textarea. I hope this is understandable, I don't have much time to write. If things are unclear, leave a comment and I will clarify soon.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not 100% on what the question is, but here is something that may help, if you have a textarea with id "content" and you replace it with the editor then you can access the instance from CKEDITOR.instances as:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.content        OR 
CKEDITOR.instances[content]       OR 
CKEDITOR.instances["content"]
```

Now when you change the id of the cloned text area to lets say "content2" and the clone editor instance is not in CKEDITOR.instances then you need to replace the clone after the id is update.

```
CKEDITOR.replace('content2');
```

So the editor will have more than one instances "content" and "content2". You can loop through the instances and verify them and use the one you need.

```
for(x in CKEDITOR.instances){
var instance = CKEDITOR.instances[x];
// do something with the instance
}
```

Comment: In your examples, you obtain the instance with the ID of the element, not the element itself, which is what I was trying to obtain.

Comment: you must be using some way to get the element, if you have the element in a jquery selector or a Ckeditor UI element then you can get id from the id property.

Comment: `CKEDITOR.instances[content]` looks broken unless you have a variable `content` with the value `'content'`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the jQuery adapter, you can get the CKEDITOR object using the following...

```
$(element).ckeditorGet();
```